# terminal dañado

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hola soy nuevo en linux e intente instalar "terminator" para manejo de terminal y me dio un problema, intente repararlo pero creo que lo dañe, inetnto abrir terminator y se abre muchisimas ventanas y no se detiene hasta que la maquina se congela,lo desintale y ahora no puedo instalar ningun otro porque hace referencia a terminator como terminal por defecto, ejecuto:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

y me sale:

Sólo hay una alternativa en el grupo de enlaces x-terminal-emulator (provee /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator): /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
Nada que configurar.

ahora abro el visual Studio Code que tiene una terminal integrado y me sale:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "terminator" does not exist.
```

no tengo idea de que podrra ser..si alguien sabe de antemano gracias....

Comment: Indica porfavor version de SO,si gnome-terminal esta instalado?  "dpkg -l | grep gnome-terminal"
Y el output de sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator

Comment: hola gracias por tu tiempo, aqui las respuestas: i  gnome-terminal 3.28.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 y la salida de sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator es  “Sólo hay una alternativa en el grupo de enlaces x-terminal-emulator (provee /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator): /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper Nada que configurar.”, de antemano gracias

Comment: Tengo una respuesta preparada ya con todo explicado, pero tengo dudas de si sera buena  o no. ejecuta un :  dpkg-reconfigure gnome-terminal, y dime si se ha solucionado el problema

Comment: NO hermano, sigue el error....

Comment: y Alt+F2   y escribir gnome-terminal.wrapper   ( ejecutar comando)